# Is there a way to have optional fields in a Circe decoder?

Tags: scala, circe

I have a case class on which every field is optional, like:

```
case class Foo(name: Option[String],
               phone: Option[String],
               email: Option[String])
```

I was trying to create a manual Decoder for my case class and found that a decoder is something like:

```
implicit val decoder: Decoder[Foo] = (c: HCursor) => {
  for {
    name <- c.downField("name").as[String]
    phone <- c.downField("phone").as[String]
    email <- c.downField("email").as[String]
  } yield {
    new Foo(name, phone, email)
  }
}
```

But checking `downField` method, if the field is not set, the cursor will chage to `FailedCursor`, so an error will rise.

How can I expect some field to be optional and return `None` if it is not defined?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just use `c.downField.as[Option[T]]`, so your code will be like this:

```
implicit val decoder: Decoder[Foo] = (c: HCursor) => {
  for {
    name <- c.downField("name").as[Option[String]]
    phone <- c.downField("phone").as[Option[String]]
    email <- c.downField("email").as[Option[String]]
  } yield new Foo(name, phone, email)
}
```